# I am trying to map python into web page.

Tags: python, html

I have few scripts written and trying to map those scripts with web page so that any user want to run a script just need to click the button on the web page and script will run at background, output will show on the web screen...

I have no idea how to proceed on this. Can someone help me  ??

Comment: read about flask web framework

Comment: The user needs guidance not downvotes.

Comment: @polarise- Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

For you to accomplish this you will need to write some backend code that initiates your script from your webserver. This is because your browser can only run JavaScript. Python would have to run on the webserver.

There are many Python frameworks that can make this task easier such as Django, Bottle and Flask.

Comment: Django, bottle and flask will help to integrate python with webserver ?

Comment: Write now i am running scripts on cmd instead need to run on web page...

Comment: Yes. They are Python frameworks for web applications so you can include the script code as part of the webserver.